# Washing for Urchatz when you eat your Karpas with a fork

Tags: passover, passover-seder-hagada, netilat-yadayim-washing

Based on the Gemara in [Pesachim 115a-b](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.115a.9?lang=he&with=Tur&lang2=he) (as explained by the primary Meforshim there) the reason we wash before Karpas is so that our hands don't make the water on the vegetables Tamei when we touch them with our unclean hands. Although most people are not Makpid on this year-round, we are concerned for this Seder night as the Levush (473:6)

> ואע"ג דבשאר ימות השנה אין נזהרין בזה, אפשר משום חיבת הרגל ושהוא טיבול של מצוה, נהגו עצמן עכשיו בטהרה יותר:

and others (Pri Megadim, Shelah Hakadosh, etc.) explain.

Does one still need to do Urchatz when they are eating their Karpas with a fork and will not be touching it at all with their hands?

Comment: This is actually a common case: Corn Flakes in milk

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/holidays/passover/pesach_cdo/aid/4333580/#footnoteRef8a4333580  I don’t have access to the source so only posting as a comment

Comment: Why would this be any different than washing for bread that you're eating without touching it?